Merging two videos using fluent-ffmpeg failing and returning 4294967274 code
I am merging two videos of different widths and heights but the mergeTofile function on its error listener is returning this error "Error ffmpeg exited with code 4294967274: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
const fs=require('fs')
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var mergedVideo =ffmpeg().setFfmpegPath('C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\ffmpeg\\tools\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe').setFfprobePath('C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\ffmpeg\\tools\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe')
fs.readdir('./scaled',(err,filename)=>{
 if(err){
  console.error(err)
 }
 filename.forEach(function(videoName){
   mergedVideo = mergedVideo.addInput('./scaled/'+videoName);
});
mergedVideo.mergeToFile('./output/output.mp4', './tmp/')
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error ' + err.message);
})
.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Finished!');
});
})

I tried to crop the videos to look almost the same but still, the error was returned
Here is my output in the console
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Error ffmpeg exited with code 4294967274: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
Conversion failed!

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Error ffmpeg exited with code 4294967274: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
Conversion failed!

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Error ffmpeg exited with code 4294967274: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
Conversion failed!

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart


4294967274 = -22 = DISK_WRITE_ERROR

Can you get more output out of ffmpeg please? It looks like you can just swap your ffmpeg() constructor for ffmpeg({ logging: console }), although that might end up being too verbose.

I have found that the problem was the bitrate, merging videos is only allowed when the bitrate is the same or incrementing. If in your array of videonames there is a video with small bitrate compared to the previous one the merge will fail.

Rework/delete files with 0 bitrate.

are you saying a file can have 0 bitrate? what does that mean? or to rework it with 0 bitrate? what does that mean?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
